WebFlux + R2DBC: How to prevent a malicious REST client from DDoSing the app via slow response consumption
I am evaluating the Spring WebFlux + R2DBC stack for our next project. Consider this textbook code for REST response streaming:
@GetMapping("items")
public Flux<Item> findAll() {
    return repository.findAll();
}

The repository executes a database query with jOOQ, but I don't think this detail is relevant to the question. I am concerned about how to prevent a REST client from holding a database connection indefinitely by slowly consuming the REST response or by quietly dropping the network connection altogether.
If my database connection pool has 20 connections, an attacker could fire 20 concurrent REST calls and then immediately go offline. This would render my application unresponsive. What's worse, it would be unresponsive indefinitely because, as far as I can tell, Spring 6 WebFlux does not configure HTTP response or socket read/write timeouts by default, and there appears to be no available configuration option to set these timeouts.
Clearly, I must be missing something or misunderstanding how this works. Can someone explain how to mitigate this risk?

"If my database connection pool has 20 connections, an attacker could fire 20 concurrent REST calls and then immediately go offline." this is partly false, as if the attacker immediately goes offline, no one will be here to subscribe to your publishing chain, hence no connection to the database would occur.

I may have been too quick to claim "immediately" before even receiving response headers. However, it definitely occurs after consuming the first item from the Flux.

There are many solutions, some of them are written by драган-јованковић. I have two more general ideas for you:
1 - decouple database-read from http-read

Don't open transactions on controller layer, only on service layer.
Use paging and make it impossible to fetch to much data within one request.

2 - scale

If you run your application in kubernetes, then you can scale horizontally up - measured at the open connections.
Use larger connections-pools.


These are generally good suggestions, thank you. However, I am concerned that the specific issue of reactive backpressure support is not addressed here. One of the selling points of reactive programming is the ability to avoid eager prefetching of query results into memory. If I want to stream items based on downstream requests, I still need to keep the database connection open, whether I move this logic into the service layer or limit the query size with paging. Giving up backpressure support and resorting to eager fetching is definitely an option, but then I don't see much value in R2DBC.

Measures you can apply some of them are related OWASP, and there measures you can do to avoid DOS or DDOS attacks.
In example :

Set the number of connections in your pool or decrease it if necessary.

Create read and write timeout to not let the connection alive for a long time.

Rate limit or backpressure handling.

Spike Arrest

Implement spike arrest policy : For this you can use a tool like resilience4j which may cut the connection to avoid discontinuity of service. (circuit breaker pattern).


You should have a config file like this :
spring:
  webflux:
    server:
      max-idle-time: 30s
      max-life-time: 60s
      max-connection-time: 30s
  r2dbc:
    pool:
      max-size: 20
server:
  reactive:
    session:
      timeout: 30s


Thank you for the help. Resilience4j looks like a great library regardless of the project stack, and I will definitely check it out. For the concern about backpressure, please see my comment to @akop. On a side note, can Flux be rate-limited in a "faster than" way? For instance, by throwing an error if the next item is not requested within a specified timeout T, resetting timer on each next call.

Yes it's possible, using timeouts and also combining errorhandling policy, you can set the number of retries to 0 with 0 delay and implement an event to show what is the content of the error, in case you just want to skip to the next one.

"If my database connection pool has 20 connections, an attacker could fire 20 concurrent REST calls and then immediately go offline. "
One of the cool things about reactive stack is - It will work only when there is a client and still subscribed to it. When subscribes and cancels, your DB operation will also be cancelled.

The problem is HTTP response subscription will never be canceled if the client silently drops the connections instead of going through standard TCP disconnect. You can test this yourself by pulling the network plug or going into airplane mode during response streaming.
